# How can I send my 4.4.2 device's SMS from the Web without changing the default app?

Tags: sms, 4.4-kitkat

I would like to be able to send SMS from my phone via the Web.

I used to use MySMS, however, since upgrading to 4.4.2, the app demands that it be the default messaging app due to messaging changes introduced in 4.4. I'm quite happy with using GoSMS and don't want to change.

What options do I have?

Comment: Check out my edit it might help you

Answer (score 1):

Sadly that's a limit of android Kit-Kat the "options" I see are:

- not to use MySMS for sending via Web, and have GoSMS as default SMS App
- Set MySMS as default SMS App, in order to send via Web
- Wait until and if in the future MySMS support that feature ie. sending via SIM without having the `default` privileges
- Find an other app that may fit both of your needs.

eg. *A quite similar app is [HOLA SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.holasms.client) it can send web SMS without being `default` (edit. That changed to the last update)
So you can buy credits for it and send web to sms with sender your Phone Number so nobody can understand that it is not a SIM message. Then setting it as `default` once in a while the messages will be synced and added to your phone.*